# Python scripting with OVITO

Tags: python

I have a quick question regarding my python code. I am using a tool called OVITO, which works quite nicely when I run in the GUI. I am trying to run it using the python scripting interface, but I am not wanting to get the results that I want.

The code should create a list of files with a single number. However, the number for each file should change. I am calculating a specific property for my material (vacancies), and I know vacancies are created, but my code says 0 for all my files. Can someone tell me if I am overwriting somehow or if something is obviously wrong? Again, I do not expect anyone here to know OVITO, but just with the python part, curious if something is clearly wrong.

```
Import OVITO modules.
    from ovito.io import *
    from ovito.modifiers import *

    # Import NumPy module.
    import numpy
    import sys

    node = import_file("../cascade.dump",multiple_frames = True)
    for i in range(node.source.num_frames):
        with open("{}.out".format(i),'w') as f:
            mod = WignerSeitzAnalysisModifier(per_type_occupancies = True)
            mod.reference.load("../../../../../../STP/position_perfect_300.dump")
            node.modifiers.append(mod)
            node.compute()
            node.modifiers.append(SelectExpressionModifier(expression = 'Occupancy.1==0&&Occupancy.2==0 && ParticleType==1'))
            node.compute()
            f.write("%i\n" % numpy.count_nonzero(node.output.particle_properties['Selection']))
        f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a very old post, but to whom it can help the solution is just to give the frame to compute in node.compute().

```
Import OVITO modules.
from ovito.io import *
from ovito.modifiers import *

# Import NumPy module.
import numpy
import sys

node = import_file("../cascade.dump",multiple_frames = True)
for i in range(node.source.num_frames):
    with open("{}.out".format(i),'w') as f:
        mod = WignerSeitzAnalysisModifier(per_type_occupancies = True)
        mod.reference.load("../../../../../../STP/position_perfect_300.dump")
        node.modifiers.append(mod)
        node.compute(i)
        node.modifiers.append(SelectExpressionModifier(expression = 'Occupancy.1==0&&Occupancy.2==0 && ParticleType==1'))
        node.compute(i)
        f.write("%i\n" % numpy.count_nonzero(node.output.particle_properties['Selection']))
    f.close()
```